# AWS Lambda FormData body with File Upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi I am currently looking for library that uses `AWS Lambda Proxy Integration` service from amazon that would help me parse `formdata` and send the data using `https` library using nodejs. A sample code will do as well on how to get the body and the file from the `formdata` request.

Please someone let me know if there is one.  Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the front-end code OR server side form handling code

Comment: Hi @SubhashisPandey, I am looking for server side form handling code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, complete the form element as per your need.

HTML form

```
    <form id="hfrm" method="POST" action="/fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    </form>
```

Use AJAX to submit the code

```
var form = $('#hfrm').get(0); 
var formData = new FormData(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "URL");
xhr.send(formData);
```

The server side code to handle the request, please note there are few places where you must use credentials and names like AWS Region, S3 bucket name etc.

```
    var xpress          = require('express')
    const fileUpload    = require('express-fileupload');
    const app           = xpress();

    app.use(fileUpload());


    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    app.post('/fileUpload', async (req, res) => {

        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: "ACCESS-KEY",
            secretAccesskey: "SECRET-ACCESS-KEY",
            region: "AWS REGION"
        })


        const s3 = new AWS.S3();

        const fileContent  = Buffer.from(req.files.uploadedFileName.data, 'binary');

        const params = {
                Bucket: 'S3 BUKET-NAME',
                Key: "Name of the File",
                Body: fileContent 
        };

        s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                res.send({
                    "response_code": 200,
                    "response_message": "Success message",
                    "response_data": data
                });
        });

    })

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('Sample app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using `AWS S3 bucket` service because we handle the data in our own database, so basically we will upload the file in our own database.

Comment: You have the file content, so can omit the S3 section and write your own DB code instead

Comment: ohhh ok ok i see now, but how about the `formdata` body content? and how to pass the formdata body including the file to the vpce api server using `https` library?

Comment: You can use JQuery Form Submit, if using API, editing my answer to add the Form submit code.